# Attention Please,Moderators! Targeted for downvoting-what can I do?

Tags: support

To Whom It May Concern,
  Ever since I've joined the Stack Exchange, my reputation points have be targeted for downvoting anonymously. There was no obvious problems with my posts and in a number of cases, there were positive replies. The pattern was the same-single or multiple downvotes with absolutely no reason or identification of user. Upset though I was, I let it go because I've seen a half a dozen other users with a similar problem here at Meta, such as [Downvoting: What are the Effects of False Negatives?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3109/downvoting-what-are-the-effects-of-false-negatives) . In each case, the response was basically to stop whining. In any event,I was building up points in spite of this,so I let it go for the time being-until the past week. I have BEEN DOWNVOTED 4 TIMES FOR 10 POINTS IN THE LAST 2 DAYS,TWICE TODAY ALONE. Every time,it is the same pattern:No obvious mathematical or etiqutte reasons for the downvotes and completely anonymous. I reported it last week via email with no response. Apparently,though,it got **someone's** attention since I received the "Citizen Patrol" badge-and shortly after that,the multiple downvotes began.
  I fear whoever these users are,they'll downvote me to 0 if I let this go unchallenged and unchecked. So can the moderators PLEASE look into this immediately? Whoever these people are,it's disappointingly childish behavior and I wish they'd get a hobby.
  Thank you for your attention. 
  Sincerely,
  Mathemagician1234

Comment: It was me, at least once.

Comment: I think I've also downvoted you at least once in the last few days.  I used to leave comments when I downvoted you, but those exchanges were rarely productive, so I don't do so anymore.

Comment: @TheChaz What YOUR problem with me is is beyond me.

Comment: This is not about *YOU, or any "issue" I (don't) have with you!* I downvoted a post that I thought was not helpful. **Your** behavio(u)r is disappointingly childish. The points mean nothing. Downvotes mean almost nothing.

Comment: @ TheChaz Uh,is it or is it not MY reputation points on this board-which I happen to take some pride in and which I work fairly hard to build up-that you're attacking for mo apparent reason? I don't know,maybe it's me,but I take that kind of personally.Adam's comments in the past have been downright insulting and demeaning.If I overreacted to your downvotes because of his involvement,I'm sorry.

Comment: Apology accepted. See you around.

Comment: This is all very amusing.

Comment: @Mathemagician1234 It has been said many times if you feel that you have been downvoted out of any reason you find that is not logical, contact the moderators discreetly and *not* make a meta post.

Comment: @Benjamin I DID that-they did not respond. This was not my FIRST course of action,believe me.They eventually did respond,after this post went up at Meta.

Comment: I had the same problem, if you can spare a minute, write an answer [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/16815/what-to-do-when-a-question-is-on-hold-and-who-closed-it-does-not-answer) and explain what happened 3 years ago.

Answer (score 12):

1. After reading this "question", I decided to pull up your answers on the main site and looked at the 50 (+/-) with lowest vote count. I upvoted for a few, and only downvoted [one](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/99178/7850) (of the ~50 surveyed).
2. I downvoted this meta question.

> **STOP WHINING**

Comment: I deleted my comment because I felt it was borderline abrasive.I still don't think your actions are appropriate on here,but it's clear there isn't much I can do about it. So have at it.

Comment: Is it not appropriate for me to downvote a question that I think is not helpful? Obviously you would not intentionally author something unhelpful, so I assume that you disagree with my opinion. There's no need to take it personally. Also, thanks for removing the hatespeech.

Answer (score 4):

We should definitely start taking rep less seriously, guys. I don't like anonymous downvotes either, but I guess sometimes we miss something other might find **not** useful. If  it really concerns you just leave a comment asking for an explanation and you'll probably get it - maybe not from the downvoter but from another user that might see the problem. I did it a few times and it sometimes **was** the case there was a mistake in the post. Anyways, I personally encourage to tell the person who posted what the mistake is; it is better for all of us. But definitely, don't make it a fuzz, take it easy and put some effort in being less sloppy or whatever the case is.